# How to only rerun a async function via a for loop once it's async operations are complete

Tags: javascript, promise, vscode-extensions

I have a function that needs to be called as many times as the `length` of `const allFiles`. I used a `for` loop to accomplish this. However, the `for` loop calls the function again and agian before the function's async operations are complete. Since the async operation `await vscode.commands.executeCommand('code-runner.run', null)` can't have two pending iterations I get an error that says `Code is already running!` (Keep in mind I'm using a third-party API for this). Here's my code:

```
        const getAllFiles = vscode.workspace.findFiles('**/*.*', '**/node_modules/**');

        const onActivation = async () => {
            const allFiles = await getAllFiles

                const runCode = async (i) => {
                    await vscode.window.showTextDocument(allFiles[i])
                    await vscode.commands.executeCommand('code-runner.run', null)
                }
                for (let i = 0; i < allFiles.length; i++) {
                    runCode(i)
                }
        }
        onActivation()
```

Comment: `await getAllFiles` Is that a typo? I would imagine that `getAllFiles` is a function that needs to be called.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "recheck" or what you are even trying to achieve.

Comment: "*However, this doesn't work.*" - please post the value of `allFiles` you got in your test, the console output, and the output you had actually expected.

Comment: Your `if` conditions don't make sense. Both your if blocks are doing essentially the same, and exactly one of them always executes. `ranCode` always will equal `i`.

Comment: @Guillaume Brunerie It's not a typo ```getAllFiles``` is not a function. ```getAllFiles``` is a variable that returns a promise. Then, ```allFiles``` converts the promise into an array of data.

Comment: @Ethan Ah ok, weird naming. But do you mean that it *is* a promise? Variables cannot return promises, only functions can.

Comment: You logs make it look like `runCode()` is executed twice. Unsure what is not right with your output.

Comment: @Guillaume It seems to work fine for me. When I use```console.log(getAllFiles)``` it returns a promise.

Comment: @epascarello Whoops! I accidentally ran the extension twice and copied both messages into the debug console (I edited the question to fix that). As for the output, nothing is wrong with it. The problem is that first ```if statement``` 1 fires immediately since it's condition is met from the start. Then before the promise in ```if statement``` 1 is resolved ```if statement``` 2 fires and only it's ```if statement``` is resolved. How do I fix this?

Comment: You still haven't explained what you actually want to achieve. The output looks fine to me. Why do you have an if statement at all given that you do the same thing in both branches? And if you defined this `getAllFiles` yourself, you should really either change the name or make it a function.

Comment: Sorry for any unclarity. I rewrote the question in an attempt to make it more clear.

Comment: If you want to run them one at a time you need to await the runCode call.

Comment: You should be doing `await runCode()`

Comment: They both still run at the same time. With the same ````Code is already running error```

Comment: Then the question becomes: do `vscode.window.showTextDocument` and `vscode.commands.executeCommand` actually return promises that can be `await`ed?